# How to erase a value from the inner map, in a map of maps in C++

Tags: c++, stdmap

In the below example, I'd like to delete just t and keep rest of the values associated with id.

```
std::map<int,map<int,Object&>> rootSet;
rootSet.erase(id,t);
```

Comment: Please read [ask[ with a [mcve]

Comment: std::map<int,map<int,Object&>> rootSet;

Comment: shouldn't it be `rootSet[id].erase(t)`?

Comment: Yes, that solves it. Thank you!

Comment: @lucieon `rootSet[id].erase(t)` has unintended consequence of adding entry for `id`, if it didn't, yet, exist.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Ah yes. It should rather be `rootSet.at(id).erase(t)`

Comment: Is that reference value type legal?

Comment: Yes, it is legal.

Comment: @lucieon That throws an exception if the `id` doesn't exist. If such a case is exceptional - depends on expected usage of such code.

Comment: `find` is the better way to go, per my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

The erase function cannot do this. You would have to do this yourself by grabbing a reference to the inner map, and calling erase on it.

```
std::map<int,std::map<int,Object&>> rootSet;
auto _where = rootSet.find(id);
if ( _where != rootSet.end() ) {
    _where->second.erase( t );
}
```

Comment: And it would be great to encapsulate that bit of logic into a nice `eraseFromRootSet(id)` function or method ...

Comment: Could probably come up with a delicious, recursive, variadic `eraseWithPath()` - use like `eraseWithPath(rootSet, id, t)` or plug in a different map type with more nested maps and more arguments to describe the path to erase :D